# Typescript ESLint declaration files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, eslint

I've googled around a bit but I can't find anything regarding this, might be because I'm not exactly sure what causing the issue.

I wanted to set a global value on the node.js global object. Just a simple string

```js
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname)
```

Since I'm using Typescript, my editor (Visual Studio Code) warned me that the property did not exist on type Global which makes sense.

I went ahead and created a `global.d.ts` in my root folder with

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
        appRoot: string;
  }
}
```

This worked perfectly and the editor tells me it's fine, but still breaks on other random properties, so everything still works.

However, this is where the issue is. When i run the following to lint and fix my code it doesn't seem the recognize my declartion file `global.d.ts` and crashing with the same error message that VS Code gave me earlier. `src/app.ts:15:8 - error TS2339: Property 'appRoot' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.`

```sh
eslint -c ./.eslintrc.js --ext .ts,.js --fix ./src/**/*.{js,ts}`
```

These are my config files

.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    env: {
        node: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        '@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    ],
    rules: {
        ...
    },
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modues"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I was having this same problem in one of my projects, after some google searching, I came across this [issue on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21344). I was able to fix my issue by first declaring the type definition in a [package](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/commit/8423f46ac583024c3f1d81e07760cf9c355eeef2#diff-66e160cc21e4a125c72d8025e5fe4e99) and then including the path to the package in `compileroptions.typeRoots`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the question mixes up two separate tools:

- **TypeScript** is the programming language you're writing in. Its tooling includes a *type checker* that can be run on the command-line (`tsc`) and integrated into editors such as VS Code.

  - TypeScript is configured with a `tsconfig.json` file.
- **ESLint** is a utility to scan (*"lint"*) code for defects based on a configurable list of rules.

  - ESLint is configured with a file with a name similar to `.eslintrc.js` or `eslint.config.js`.

The question uses the word *"lint"* but ESLint isn't relevant here. The error in question is a TypeScript *type checking* complaint.

The issue here is probably that the `tsconfig.json` specifies `include: ["src/**/*.ts"]` but the `global.d.ts` file is outside of that directory. Try moving it to be `src/global.d.ts`. If that fails, explicitly include the path to the global types in the TSConfig's `include`.